# dataframe column cast astype() not casting to float from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, casting

## Simple data type conversion

Pandas Data Frame astype() not casting to float.

Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Temperature'

## Effort

Attempted two approaches to string strip() to clean invisible chars from df['Temperature']

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df["Temperature"] = df['Temperature'].str.strip().astype(float)
```

Even tried astype()

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float64), axis=1)
```

Still get same ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Temperature'

Data
df['Temperature']

```
0      29
1      29
2      26
3      25
4      27
       ..
242    30
243    28
244    27
245    24
246    24
Name: Temperature, Length: 245, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Temperature'
```

It seems like there is at least one row in the column/series `df['Temperature']` that equals to `Temperature`.

Try to clean up your column before calling [**`pandas.Series.astype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) :

```
df["Temperature"] = df['Temperature'].replace('Temperature', np.nan).astype(float)
```

Or use [**`pandas.to_numeric`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) :

```
df['Temperature'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Temperature'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: excellent point. there may be some corruption in my data source on Kaggle, as this clean up code you shared only solved some of the issue